# Python Dynamic Import import as

Tags: python, python-import

I'm trying to make a python based proof of concept system, and it has a "runcode" command,

I need to import code put into the file to run it, but dynamically, and with an alias

what I need:

```py
import program-name as program
```

but a version for dynamics like this

```py
__import__(program-name-variable)
```

but

```py
__import__(program-name-variable) as program
```

doesn't work

Comment: `program = __import__(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assign the variable with the needed name that you would normally put after "as"

```
program = __import__(program-name-variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

someone found out the obvious answer I **somehow** missed, it was

program = **import**(...)